# Count lines in a text without empty liines

Tags: c#

I'm using next code to count lines in a text i have.
It's work fine but I don't want to count empty lines.
How can I do it, but with saving the current code format?

```
var lineCount = 0;
using (var readerlines = File.OpenText(strfilename))
{
    while (readerlines.ReadLine() != null)
    {
        lineCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: I suggest using LINQ and using  `string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check if the line is not an empty string

```
var lineCount = 0;
string line = string.Empty;
using (var readerlines = File.OpenText(strfilename))
{
    while ((line = readerlines.ReadLine()) != null)
    {
        if (!line.Equals(string.Empty))
        {
            lineCount++;
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: I got an error for the first example (on the word equals) and the second give me wrong line numbers (very low)

Comment: @CobyAbutbul What is the error?

Comment: @CobyAbutbul nevermined, should be Equals with capital letter

Comment: It is working great. Thanks

Answer (score 4):

You can try like this:

```
int lineCount = File.ReadLines(@"yourfile.txt")
                    .Count(line => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(line));
```

Answer (score 0):

Or this:

```
string data = File.ReadAllText(strfilename);
string[] lines = data.Split(new char[] {'\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
int line_count = lines.Length;
```

In short:

```
int line_count = File.ReadAllText(strfilename).Split(new char[] {'\n' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Length;
```